# How to add coupon to *Stripe subscription* with Laravel Cashier after subscription already created

Tags: php, laravel-4, stripe-payments, laravel-cashier

According to the Stripe documentation, it appears as though you can actually apply coupons to a customer as a whole, but you can also apply coupons to their subscriptions. I am trying to apply a coupon to the customer's subscription after the subscription has already been created. I am using Laravel Cashier 4.2.

Here is what I have tried:

```
 $company = Auth::user()->company;
 $customer = $company->subscription()->getStripeCustomer(); // returns a StripeGateway object
 $customer->subscription->applyCoupon($input['coupon_code']);
```

Here is the error message:

```
"Call to undefined method Stripe_Subscription::updateSubscription()"
```

I can use the `applyCoupon()` method to a customer as a whole, but not an actual subscription... Ideas appreciated.

The Stripe documentation only shows how to remove a discount from a subscription:
[Discount Object](https://stripe.com/docs/api#discount_object). The only other information I've been able to find in their documentation is:

> Coupons and discounts
>
> If you want to provide discounts to certain customers, you can create coupon codes in the Dashboard. Coupons have a discount percentage and a duration, so you could create coupons like a 10% lifetime discount, or a one month 50% discount, etc. Coupons can also have expiration dates attached, after which they can't be used. Here's an example of adding a discount to a user's subscription. In this case, we've already created a coupon called 50OFF1MONTH:
>
> `curl https://api.stripe.com/v1/customers/cus_4fdAW5ftNQow1a \
>      -u sk_test_4LOIhlh19aUz8yFBLwMIxnBY: \
>      -d coupon=50OFF1MONTH`

However, this isn't very helpful. Once again, Laravel's documentation is a little to elegant, and it's missing any info on the topic.

I wonder if I just need to recreate the subscription object entirely with the new coupon... But that's not ideal because you need a card token for that.

**Update 1**

I can confirm that this does in fact apply a coupon to the **subscription** itself

```
$user->subscription('monthly')
 ->withCoupon('code')
 ->create($creditCardToken);
```

However, once again the question is how can a coupon be added after the fact.

Answer (score 5):

Starting with Cashier v11.* there are new [convenience methods](https://github.com/laravel/cashier-stripe/pull/943) to update the underlying Stripe subscription object. To apply a coupon to the user's Subscription model instead of the Customer model, try this in the controller:

```
$user->subscription('default')->updateStripeSubscription(['coupon' => $couponCode]);
```

To remove the coupon from the subscription, send an update request and pass an empty coupon string. As described under [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58634940/remove-coupon-from-stripe-subscription-in-update), a coupon set to an empty string removes it, while passing *null* is ignored.

```
$user->subscription('default')->updateStripeSubscription(['coupon' => '']);
```

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't look like what I'm trying to do is possible, so I found another way. All I do is swap the users existing plan to the current plan and use the `withCoupon` method. This does appear to apply the coupon to the subscription and doesn't seem to charge the user or change their billing period, but I could be wrong...

```
$company->subscription($company->stripe_plan)
        ->withCoupon($input['coupon_code'])
        ->swap();
```

Comment: I'm wondering did you end up experiencing any difficulties with this?

Comment: From what I recall @Rob no. But this project is long done!

Comment: @Marcel, may I ask you to take a look at a l Stripe rekated question here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62238551/stripe-cannot-create-a-plan ?

Answer (score 1):

Adding a Coupon to an Existing Subscription.
You can also use cashier method as below:

```
try {
$user->applyCoupon('coupon_code');
return redirect()->back()->withMessage('Coupon Applied');  
} catch (Exception $e) {
return back()->withError($e->getMessage());
}
```

When applying a coupon, it's best to wrap this in a try / catch block because if the user enters an invalid coupon, Stripe will return an exception with the reason for the failure.

Answer (score 1):

For everyone who can't find an easy and convenient way to swap the subscriptions with a coupon, here's what I came up with recently.

First of all, we'll have to create a custom `Subscription` eloquent model and extend `Laravel\Cashier\Subscription` class.

Now we're going to create the `withCoupon()` method there:

```
public function withCoupon($coupon)
{
    $this->coupon = $coupon;

    return $this;
}
```

The next thing will be extending the original `swap()` method and adding the coupon part. Just copy and paste the original method and add this piece of code somewhere before the `$subscription->save();` line.

```php
...
// Applying the discount coupon if such exists
if ($this->coupon) {
     $subscription->coupon = $this->coupon;
}
...
$subscription->save();
```

The last thing you've got to do in order to make things work properly is to create a custom `Billable` trait and change `subscriptions()` method to use your custom `Subscription` model.

After that, you can apply your very own `Billable` trait to the billable model and apply coupons while swapping plans.

```php
$user
    ->subscription($product)
    ->withCoupon($coupon)
    ->swap($plan);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Laravel 7.x with Cashier 10 you have the applyCoupon() method on a Billable (User) model.

Something like this in the controller:

```
 /**
 * Apply Stripe coupon
 */
public function applyCoupon(Request $request){

    $user = $request->user();
    if ($user->subscribedToPlan('plan_name', 'default')) {
        try {
            $user->applyCoupon($request->couponCode);
            return redirect('subscription')->withMessage('Coupon Applied');
        }  catch (\Exception $e) {
            return redirect('subscription')->withError($e->getMessage());
        }
    } 
}
```