# Remove Coupon from Stripe Subscription in Update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, stripe-payments, ruby-on-rails-5.2

I need to remove a coupon on a subscription during update, I thought passing coupon of nil to the api should remove it, but it just removes it from the post.

There is another way of doing it like this.. 
https://stripe.com/docs/api/discounts/subscription_delete

but it requires another call I don't want to do.

#### Ruby Stripe Gem API:

```
      Stripe::Subscription.update(
        subscription.stripe_id,
        {
          coupon: nil,
          items: [
            {
              id: subscription.item_stripe_id,
              quantity: 0,

            },
            { 
              plan: to_plan.stripe_id,
              quantity: 1
            }
          ],
        }
      )
```

#### creates a post request like this:

```
{
  "items": {
    "0": {
      "id": "si_G5sdf33t89",
      "quantity": "0"
    },
    "1": {
      "plan": "a_plan",
      "quantity": "1"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 12):

```
coupon: ''
```

Coupon set to an empty string removes it, while nil/null is ignored

Answer (score 0):

This works for me for discounts as well.

```
discount: ''
```